# How to map groups belonging to a User in Azure AD provisioning call

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am setting up an SSO Enterprise APP in Azure AD and there is a feature called provisioning which requires a Scim endpoint for Azure AD to sync users between the SAAS app AD in "real-time"

The application grants access to a user based on the groups the user belongs too. This works well when SAML is used because i can include the groups as part of the SAML request, but i am having a lot of trouble mapping the groups in the Scim call, using the Provisioning functionality, so that the user does not need to launch the app to be provisioned.

Is there a way i can map the groups a User belongs to as part of the provisioning call?

I have tried mapping different values in `customappsso` config with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD Provisioning manages group objects directly and populates values into each group's "members" attribute. The SCIM protocol does not allow manipulation of a user's group memberships via updates targeted to the user itself.

You should just need to ensure that your SCIM endpoint supports calls to /groups, that you have groups enabled in provisioning, and that the groups are assigned/otherwise in scope for provisioning in the AAD app.

Comment: so there is no way i can pass the groups as part of the users attributes along with the other properties? for example `{displayName: 'John', groups: [{id: 123, name: 'group1'}]}`

Comment: Correct - the only way this data can be sent from AAD to a SCIM endpoint is via the "members" attribute of a group object.